# Filling shape with particles canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, particle-system, particles

Just wondering if anyone could point me in a good direction to a way I could fill an irregular shape with particles, in rows, which would then be animatable.

This is the closest example i can find - http://www.wkams.com/#!/work/detail/coca-cola-music-vis

The two ways I can think would work is work out the density I want, map out how many particles would be needed for each row, and position accordingly. This way seems quite timely and not very robust.

The second way, which I can't seem to figure out how I would do it, is draw the shape in the canvas, then generatively fill the shape with particles, keeping them in the constraints of the shape.

Any general concept of how this could be done would be greatly appreciated.

Let me know if it doesn't make sense.

Cheers

Comment: What type of particles do you want? Like snow, or rain? Or randomly floating? Do they bounce off the edges?

Comment: A fairly rigid grid of particles than can have dynamics applied, very similar to the example of the coke bottle. imagine if the white circular particles weren't animated around the bottle and were just in rows. does that make sense? sorry, little new to all this.

Answer (score 11):

We start by drawing the shape we want on canvas.

This shape may be anything. It may be text, it may be a shape in an image - the non-transparent part of a .png with transparency, the non-black or the black part of a .jpg image - it doesn't really matter, all of these work.

Let's start with the very simple case where the shape is text.

We're going to have a few constants (the canvas, the context, the number of RGBA channels, a text box object which starts out with just the string we want to dottify, the dot grid for which we define the dot radius and the distance between two consecutive dots on the same row/ column):

```
const _C = document.getElementById('c'), 
      CT = _C.getContext('2d'), 
      TEXT_BOX = { str: 'HELLO!' }, 
      DOT_GRID = { gap: 6 }, 
      NUM_CH = 'RGBA'.length;
```

We set canvas dimensions and then we compute a few things about the text so that it nicely fits in the middle of the canvas. Not all letters are going to need a square box, some (like 'I') are much narrower, but we can start from such an assumption to get the height of our text box, which we also store in the text box object and set as the font size:

```
TEXT_BOX.height = Math.min(.7*_C.height, _C.width/TEXT_BOX.str.length);
CT.font = `600 ${TEXT_BOX.height}px arial black, sans serif`;
CT.letterSpacing = '8px';
```

We've also spaced out the letters a bit.

We then measure the text with this font size and letter spacing in order to get the actual text box width. We also compute the coordinates of the top left corner (we'll be using these when dottifying the text).

```
TEXT_BOX.width = CT.measureText(TEXT_BOX.str).width;
TEXT_BOX.x = .5*(_C.width - TEXT_BOX.width);
TEXT_BOX.y = .5*(_C.height - TEXT_BOX.height);
```

We give the text a custom fill style (this is totally optional and only really needed if you plan on leaving the text visible underneath the grid of dots) and middle align it along both its own vertical and horizontal axes.

```
CT.fillStyle = 'purple';
CT.textAlign = 'center';
CT.textBaseline = 'middle';
```

Now we can actually draw our text on the canvas:

```
CT.fillText(TEXT_BOX.str, .5*_C.width, .5*_C.height);
```

[image: Illustration showing the text in its text box and the alignment axes.]

Now comes the interesting part - we dottify the text!

We start out by getting the canvas image data for the text box rectangle.

```
let data = CT.getImageData(TEXT_BOX.x, TEXT_BOX.y, 
                           TEXT_BOX.width, TEXT_BOX.height).data;
```

This gives us a very long 1D array with the RGBA values of all the pixels within the text box rectangle, row by row, column by column.

```
/* 1st row, 1st column: */
R0, G0, B0, A0, 
/* 1st row, 2nd column: */
R1, G1, B1, A1, 
... 
/* last row, last column: */
RN, GN, BN, AN
```

We then turn this array into a an array of pixel objects, each pixel object containing the `x,y` coordinates of each pixel and the RGBA channel values as an array. We then filter out all pixels where the alpha is `0` (outside the text shape) and which aren't grid nodes for a grid of dots with the given gap. This basically gives us the array of dots we want to draw within the text shape.

```
DOT_GRID.arr = 
  data.reduce((a, c, i, o) => {
    if(i%NUM_CH === 0) 
      a.push({
        x: (i/NUM_CH)%TEXT_BOX.width + TEXT_BOX.x, 
        y: Math.floor(i/NUM_CH/TEXT_BOX.width) + TEXT_BOX.y, 
        rgba: o.slice(i, i + NUM_CH) 
      });
    return a
  }, []).filter(c => c.rgba[NUM_CH - 1] && 
                     !(Math.ceil(c.x - .5*DOT_GRID.gap)%DOT_GRID.gap) && 
                     !(Math.ceil(c.y - .5*DOT_GRID.gap)%DOT_GRID.gap));
```

We can remove the text underneath the dots if we want to.

```
CT.clearRect(TEXT_BOX.x, TEXT_BOX.y, TEXT_BOX.width, TEXT_BOX.height);
```

We then draw the dots, let's say with a `gold` fill.

```
CT.fillStyle = 'gold'

CT.beginPath();

DOT_GRID.arr.forEach(c => {
  CT.moveTo(c.x, c.y);
  CT.arc(c.x, c.y, DOT_GRID.rad, 0, 2*Math.PI)
});

CT.closePath();
CT.fill();
```

One thing that I would like to point out here is that fills are computationally expensive, so in this case, where all dots have the same fill style, we are keeping `fill()` outside the `forEach` loop, so it only gets called once at the end.

In general, if something doesn't need to depend on the loop variable or to be randomly generated with each iteration, keep it out of the loop!

This is what the dottified result looks like with the original text written underneath:

[image: dottified text on top of original text]

... and without:

[image: dottified text without the original underneath]

And that's pretty much it for the very basic dottifying text case.

Here's a working snippet of the very basic case explained above.

```js
const _C = document.getElementById('c'), 
      CT = _C.getContext('2d'), 
      TEXT_BOX = { str: 'HELLO!' }, 
      DOT_GRID = { rad: 2, gap: 6 }, 
      NUM_CH = 'RGBA'.length;

DOT_GRID.draw = function() {
  CT.fillStyle = 'gold';
  CT.beginPath();
  DOT_GRID.arr.forEach(c => {
    CT.moveTo(c.x, c.y);
    CT.arc(c.x, c.y, DOT_GRID.rad, 0, 2*Math.PI)
  });
  CT.closePath();
  CT.fill();
}

function dottify() {
  let data = CT.getImageData(TEXT_BOX.x, TEXT_BOX.y, 
                             TEXT_BOX.width, TEXT_BOX.height).data;
  DOT_GRID.arr = 
    data.reduce((a, c, i, o) => {
      if(i%NUM_CH === 0) 
        a.push({
          x: (i/NUM_CH)%TEXT_BOX.width + TEXT_BOX.x, 
          y: Math.floor(i/NUM_CH/TEXT_BOX.width) + TEXT_BOX.y, 
          rgba: o.slice(i, i + NUM_CH) 
        });
      return a
    }, []).filter(c => c.rgba[NUM_CH - 1] && 
                       !(Math.ceil(c.x - .5*DOT_GRID.gap)%DOT_GRID.gap) && 
                       !(Math.ceil(c.y - .5*DOT_GRID.gap)%DOT_GRID.gap));
  /* remove text... if you want to *
  CT.clearRect(TEXT_BOX.x, TEXT_BOX.y, TEXT_BOX.width, TEXT_BOX.height);
  /**/
  DOT_GRID.draw();
}

function write() {
  TEXT_BOX.height = Math.min(.7*_C.height, _C.width/TEXT_BOX.str.length);
  CT.font = `600 ${TEXT_BOX.height}px arial black, sans serif`;
  CT.letterSpacing = '8px';
  TEXT_BOX.width = Math.ceil(CT.measureText(TEXT_BOX.str).width);
  TEXT_BOX.x = Math.floor(.5*(_C.width - TEXT_BOX.width));
  TEXT_BOX.y = Math.floor(.5*(_C.height - TEXT_BOX.height));
  CT.textAlign = 'center';
  CT.textBaseline = 'middle';
  CT.fillStyle = 'purple';
  CT.fillText(TEXT_BOX.str, .5*_C.width, .5*_C.height);
  dottify();
}

(_ => {
  let s = getComputedStyle(_C);
  _C.width = +s.width.slice(0, -2);
  _C.height = +s.height.slice(0, -2);
  write();
})();
```

```css
html, body { display: grid }

html { height: 100% }

body { background: #121212 }

canvas { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

```html
<canvas id='c'></canvas>
```

And here's a [heavily commented version](https://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/ZEmoWgx?editors=0010) that also nicely handles page resize.

---

Of course, we can also give the text a gradient fill and then use the gradient-generated RGB pixel values for the dots on our grid. Which can also have different radii, a random component to their position and a motion depending on that of the pointer, like in [this example](https://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/VwVXYzX) (note that in this case I cleared the original text drawn on the canvas).

[image: Animated gif. Shows the "HOVER!" string made up of particles whose backgrounds sort of follow a gradient and which get repelled by the proximity of the mouse cursor.]

---

It works in a very similar manner for images. We draw the images on canvas, read the image data, decide on which pixels we want to exclude (maybe transparent, maybe black, maybe white... it doesn't matter) and then only keep the grid node pixels not excluded at the previous step.

Let's say we have this cat image (.png with transparency). We exclude the transparent pixels and then exclude all pixels that are not grid nodes.

[image: dark silhouette of cat walking]

We can use a Base64 image source to avoid CORS issues. There are plenty of websites that can do the conversion (for example [this one](https://www.base64-image.de/)).

We copy it and set it to a `BASE64_SRC` constant.

The constants are pretty much the same, it's just `TEXT_BOX` that gets replaced with `IMG_RECT`:

```
const IMG_RECT = { img: new Image() }
```

Once we've set canvas dimensions, we don't write the text on the canvas, but instead proceed to painting the image.

We set the image source to the Base64 one.

```
IMG_RECT.img.src = BASE64_SRC;
```

Once it has loaded, we proceed to getting its aspect ratio out of its dimensions. Then we get the dimensions and the top left corner of the box we draw our image in such that it fits within the canvas. And then we actually draw the image within this rectangle.

```
IMG_RECT.img.onload = function() {
  IMG_RECT.ratio = IMG_RECT.img.width/IMG_RECT.img.height;
  IMG_RECT.width = 
    Math.min(IMG_RECT.img.width, _C.width, _C.height*IMG_RECT.ratio);
  IMG_RECT.height = 
    Math.min(IMG_RECT.img.height, _C.height, _C.width/IMG_RECT.ratio);
  IMG_RECT.x = .5*(_C.width - IMG_RECT.width);
  IMG_RECT.y = .5*(_C.height - IMG_RECT.height);

  CT.drawImage(IMG_RECT.img, IMG_RECT.x, IMG_RECT.y, 
                             IMG_RECT.width, IMG_RECT.height);
}
```

The dottifying part is exactly the same as before, we just replace all occurrences of `TEXT_BOX` with `IMG_RECT`. And thus we have the dottified cat:

[image: dottified cat over original]

Just like in the case of the text, we can remove the original shape from underneath the dots:

[image: dottified cat with original removed from underneath]

Here's a [heavily commented demo](https://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/mdQLYBo?editors=0010) showing this in action.

We don't really have to Base64 our image. We can do this instead:

```
const IMG_RECT = {
  img: new Image(), 
  src: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/KleBk.png'
}
```

And then...

```
IMG_RECT.img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
IMG_RECT.img.src = IMG_RECT.src;
```

Here's the [live demo](https://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/poQKzjj?editors=0010) with this CORS setting in action.

---

We also don't necessarily need an image with transparency. We could also use an image like this one, where the dark shape of the ballet dancer contrasts strongly with the background.

[image: silhouette of a ballet dancer]

In this case, we need to change the first filter condition. We don't need the alpha (fourth) channel to be non-zero, but rather all the other channels (RGB, the first three) to all be pretty low values (I suppose summing them would also do the trick in this particular case):

```
Math.max(...c.rgba.slice(0, 3)) < 36
```

This pretty much does it ([live demo](https://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/vYQrBpv?editors=0010)):

[image: ballet dancer dottified]

---

Works the same way for this palm tree image:

[image: dark palm tree silhouette]

Dottified version ([live demo](https://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/VwVdZJN?editors=0010)):

[image: dottified palm tree]

---

We can also go the other way and dottify what's not dark in an image:

[image: profile]

In this case in particular, we can just focus on the blue (third) channel and use the following filter condition:

```
c.rgba[2] > 200
```

[Live demo](https://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/JjeZjGw?editors=0011).

[image: dottified profile]

---

Just like in the case of the gradient text, we can also use the RGB values from the original image for the dottified version.

Let's say we start from this image:

[image: Hail Lucipurr. Shows a cat with horns and a pentagram on its chest]

Dottifying it to preserve the RGB channels gives us this ([live demo](https://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/MWzXWLP)):

[image: Hail Lucipurr dottified.]

---

[This demo](https://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/gpZaMw) (note it's almost a decade old, JS got better and hopefully so did I... in any case, that code could be improved) uses a similar technique to turn an image into a grid of tiles which then collapse.

Answer (score 2):

**You can use compositing to restrict your particles inside an irregular shape**

[image][image]

For each loop of your animation:

- Clear the canvas.
- Draw your irregular shape on the canvas.
- Set compositing to 'source-atop'.  This will cause any new drawings to appear *only if any newly drawn pixel is over an existing opaque pixel*. This is the secret to restricting your particles to be drawn only inside your irregular shape.
- Draw your rows of particles.  All particles will appear only inside the shape.

Here's example code and a Demo.  My example just animates the size of each particle row. You can apply your design requirements to change the size & position of each row.

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
//
ctx.fillStyle='skyblue';

var PI2=Math.PI*2;
//
var w=132;
var h=479;
//
var x1=29;
var x2=177;
var x3=327;
//
var nextTime=0;
var delay=16*2;
var isFading=true;
var isComplete=false;
var opacity=100;

var imgCount=2;
var img=new Image();img.onload=start;img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/coke.png";
var label=new Image();label.onload=start;label.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/label.png";
function start(){
  console.log(imgCount);
  if(--imgCount>0){return;}

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  $('#again').click(function(){
    nextTime=0;
    delay=16*2;
    opacity=100;
    isFading=true;
  });
}

function overlay(clipX,x,alpha){
  ctx.globalAlpha=alpha;
  ctx.drawImage(img,clipX,0,w,h,x,0,w,h);
}

function fillParticles(radius,margin){
  var rr=radius*2+margin;
  ctx.save();
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  overlay(x3,50,1.00);   
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-atop';
  ctx.beginPath();
  var rows=parseInt(ch/(rr))-2;
  var cols=parseInt(cw/rr);
  for(var r=0;r<rows;r++){
    for(var c=0;c<cols;c++){
      ctx.arc(c*rr,h-(r*rr),radius,0,PI2);
      ctx.closePath();
    }}
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.restore();
  overlay(x2,50,1.00);
}

function animate(time){

  if(!isComplete){ requestAnimationFrame(animate); }

  if(time<nextTime){return;}

  if(isFading){
    if(--opacity>0){
      ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
      overlay(x1,50,opacity/100);
      overlay(x2,50,1.00);
    }else{
      isFading=false;
      overlay(x2,50,1.00);
      ctx.drawImage(label,70,210);            
      nextTime=time+1000;
    }
  }else{
    delay=1000;
    fillParticles(parseInt(Math.random()*8)+2,3);         
    ctx.drawImage(label,70,210);            
    nextTime=time+delay;
  }

}
```

```css
body{ background-color:white; padding:10px; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id=again>Again</button>
<br>
<canvas id="canvas" width=250 height=500></canvas>
```

Comment: That's great! Much better than my answer, I didn't know `source-atop` existed!

Answer (score 0):

If I were to approach this problem, I would go about it in this way:

1. Create an object that can be used to "create" particles.
2. Create as many new instances of that object as is needed for the required density.

So, basically, all the work is done by one function constructor/object.

You want this object to provide methods to draw itself to the canvas, store its x and y coordinates, its velocity and direction.

Then you can create instances of this object with the new keyword and set their x and y coordinates to spread them across a grid.

Comment: great. thanks for this.

I've got the particle creation and positioning down, i think. It's just the mapping to an object in rows that I can't seem to work out. As I mentioned, I could position this manually I imagine - say it's a triangle, row one would be one particle, row two would be two particles, row three would be three particles - for eaxample. but would there be a way the particles could fill a shape, that i've drawn, autonomosly - starting at the top left point, and detecting edges to break to a new row. Am i over thinking this?

Comment: @user3244169 How are you drawing your polygon? If it's by means of a turtle, you can have the turtle save its coordinates at certain points, so you know that the particles can use those coordinates to stay within the confines of the shape. Or, if you know the vertices, it won't be very difficult either: you just need to make sure that your particle coordinates are within the region bounded by the vertices, you can create inequalities using the vertices of the shape to define the area enclosed by it.

Comment: @user3244169 check out source-atop to draw only if there are already opaque pixels beneath.